# Password console application with the use of a while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, passwords, console-application, limit

So basically I'm trying to write a console application where it asks the user for a password and will continue to ask for it only three times and then stop with the use of a 'while' loop, but it keeps on looping and asking me for the password even if the correct password was used and after I entered it more that 3 times.

```
const string pass = "Password";            
string attempt;

do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter password: ");
    attempt = Console.ReadLine();

    if (attempt == pass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access granted.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access denied.");
    }
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const string pass = "Password";            
string attempt;

int n = 0;
do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter password: ");
    attempt = Console.ReadLine();

    if (attempt == pass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access granted.");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access denied.");
        n++;
    }
} while (n<=3);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to ask user password three time until correct one entered and stop asking if user enter correct on. You can do it by for loop

```
const string pass = "Password";            
string attempt;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter password: ");
    attempt = Console.ReadLine();

    if (attempt == pass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access granted.");
        i = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access denied.");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
const string pass = "Password";            
string attempt;
int attempt = 0;

do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter password: ");
    attempt = Console.ReadLine();

    if (attempt == pass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access granted.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access denied.");
        attempt++;
    }
} while (attempt <= 3 && attempt != pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         string pass = "";

        while (pass != "password")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter your password here");
            pass = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (pass == "password")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("your password is correct");
            }
      }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Your answer does not conform to the requirements (ask 3 times, then abort) and it also loops infinitely even if the password was correct. You should also not hardcode the password but use a variable like in the question.